# How can we use the "name" or "id" attribute values as the data property in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am working on an SPA application where I have a list of data variables that are used as the `<option>` tags in the `dropdown`. I want to navigate to another page on the `@change` event of the `dropdown` therefore I want to use either the `id` or `name` of the `select` command as the name of the data property. Here is what I mean:

Here is what I have in the `data` function:

```
data(){
  return {
      participants: [
          { value: 0, linkText: '', linkTerm: 'Select' },
          { value: 1, linkText: '/meetings/participants/create', linkTerm: 'Add New' },
          { value: 2, linkText: '/meetings/participants', linkTerm: 'All Participants' },
      ],
      positions: [
          { value: 0, linkText: '', linkTerm: 'Select' },
          { value: 1, linkText: '/meetings/positions/create', linkTerm: 'Add New' },
          { value: 2, linkText: '/meetings/positions', linkTerm: 'All Positions' },
      ],

  }
}
```

Here is the `select` tag where I use the above `data` variables as the `<option>` tag:

```
<select name="participants" id="participants" class="select-field" @change="changeRoute($event)">
  <option v-for="p in participants" :value="p.value">{{ p.linkTerm }}</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to have one function `changeRoute($event)` from which I will navigate to different pages, therefore I want to use the `id` or `name` value as the `data` property, here is the function:

```
methods:{
    changeRoute($event){
        var name = $event.target.name;
        var value = document.getElementById($event.target.id).value;
    }
}
```

Here in the above function I want to use the `name` as the `data` property as below:

```
I want to write this:  
this.name[value].linkText;
```

And because `name` here is the name of the tag which is actually `participants` so the above line of code should mean something like this:

```
this.participants[value].linkText
```

And that should return the `linkText` of the `participants` object of the `data` function.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below line

```
this.name[value].linkText;
```

to

```
this[name][value].linkText;
```